# "one years old"

Tags: expressions

I just heard someone say:

> "my baby just turned one years old"

Which sounds super weird to me - so I googled a little and found similar sentences:

> How Old Are Dogs When They Turn 1 Years Old in Human Years
>   It has been said that a dog who is 1 years old is 7 years old in human years.

Can you really say "years" after "one"?

Comment: It's apparently a template filled in: "My baby just turned ____ years old", if not the enthusiasm of a non-native speaker.  The second example gives away clearly that it's a template filled in.

Comment: You can Google and find the weirdest stuff, so?

Comment: Well my point is that what I heard was not just an isolated case

Comment: "Ungrammaticality" is not all that isolated, it's quite pervasive today, even more so in speech.

Comment: That second example is interesting. :) It made me think for a while, as to what all might be going on in that sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a quaint way of speaking which some people fall into, thinking for some reason it is correct - I think!

I have heard people say 'one pounds, fifteen pence', or the most ridiculous example was listed on an invoice from a funeral director, which I saw. It said '1 no. stained oak veneered coffins'.

Comment: Yes I agree with that currency part, in India too people commonly use the phrase "One rupees" when the correct usage should be "One Rupee"

Comment: A *penny* and *tuppence* = 2p (two pennies). Fifty pence = 50p. No?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think *tuppence* means 'two pence'. This relates back to the pre-1971 money. Nowadays people say 2p, 6p, 50p etc. But in those days it was *tuppence, thripence, fourpence, etc up to elevenpence*. Twelve pence equalled one shilling.

Comment: So "fifteen pence" is not wrong, just the bit with "One pounds" I thought I'd been saying it wrong all these years :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, you are right. I suppose we do say fifteen pence, 50 pence etc. What we don't say any longer is 'tuppence'. But that is perhaps because there is almost nothing you can buy for tuppence!

Comment: Quaint or not, it is not grammatical, neither of the OP's examples is correct.

Comment: @Kris Exactly my point. It is NOT correct.

Comment: Kris strikes again... sigh